# any way to merge disk partitions on same drive (Windows)?

Tags: partition

I have two partitions on an SSD drive (8GB and 24GB), since when installing Windows it accidentially sliced off a small partition rather than using the whole drive.

Is there anyway to merge these partitions (or remove the 24GB one, and resize the 8GB one to the whole drive size)?

Or, would it just make better sense to backup the system and reinstall?  I can easily copy the data on the 24GB drive to USB drive and back again.  But moving the C: drive with Windows already installed will be difficult w/o doing a system backup, I'm assuming.

Thanks,
Kirk

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, assuming Windows 7 (and Vista, IIRC):

1. Open Disk Management (Right-click My Computer, Properties, Storage, Disk Management)
2. Delete the 24Gb partition (back it up first if you want to keep what's on it)
3. Right-click the 8Gb partition and choose "Extend Volume"
4. Follow the wizard
5. Profit!

Other than that there are dozens of utilities that will do this for you. The best used to be Partition Magic, but it was discontinued by Symantec/Norton years ago

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought the "Extend Volume" is only available for so called "Dynamic" disks, or is that now the default?

Comment: @John, this is true for Dynamic Disks (one partition spanning multiple volumes) but the wording for making a partition larger also reads "Extend Volume" (at least on my machine it does). But that's also why this question really belongs on superuser, as no decent sysadmin would ever use a spanned volume.

Comment: Fair points. ;)